# Объединить синонимичные метки {“color”, “цвета”}

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить, так эти метки охватывают схожий круг вопросов:

- [color](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color) - 77 вопросов;
- [цвета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0) - 26 вопросов.

(по состоянию на 03.07.2017)

Comment: А не сжечь бы эти метки?

Comment: По-моему, там есть вопросы именно про цвет - восприятие цвета, выбор цвета, смешение цветов. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458599/ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676477/ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662123/ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/673991/

Comment: В том-то и дело, что вроде и про цвет и вроде и ни о чём… По факту всё равно вряд ли кто-то будет отвечать что-то про цвета без привязки к платформе.

Comment: 1) Мне кажется, [вот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458650/208926) без привязки к платформе. 2) "[Метка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags) — это ключевое слово, позволяющее отнести ваш вопрос в одну категорию с другими похожими вопросами. Благодаря подбору правильных меток другие участники смогут проще найти ваш вопрос и быстрее дать на него ответ." Где необходимость привязывать или не привязывать к платформе?